# How to edit a control content in an array inside of a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I got the following:

```
List<TextBox[]> ListMonths = new List<TextBox[]>();
```

I use it for store the same textboxes for each month, I fill it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
{
    ......

    TextBox[] TBaux = new TextBox[18];
    for (int o = 0; o <= 17; o++)
    {
        TBaux[o] = (TextBox)element.FindName("TB" + o + i);
    }
    ListMonths.Add(TBaux);
}
```

So that way I got the textboxes for each month in `ListMonths`.

How can I modify the Text property of one of the textbox (for instance `textbox[2]`) that is stored in one of the month lists (for instance `ListMonths[1]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListMonths[1][2].Text = "blabla";
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = ListMonths[1];
TextBox textBox = textBoxes[2];
textBox.Text = "blabla";
```

Comment: I would've said `ListMonths[1][2].Text = "blabla";`

Comment: missed it ahaha